# Add marker directly on streetview

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-street-view

I´m working with google maps API V3.

I have a google map with a click listener, and when you click on the map, y put a marker on the lat,lng clicked.

Is it posible to add a listener in streetview, where on click or rigthclick I can add a marker directly on the point clicked?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [**You must not store any content**](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1_3)